# Matlab: error message "??? The library 'ImfilterBuildable' is not supported by the current target, language or compiler."

Tags: matlab

Program: Matlab R2014a.
Issues:
I tries to translate matlab code to Cortex-M3 C code by Matlab code.
The following error message shown:
"??? The library 'ImfilterBuildable' is not supported by the current target, language or compiler."
I can not find related information by key word "ImfilterBuildable".
And it is workable when choose the platform as "Host computer".
Do any one can support this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Albert Ke

Comment: Which MATLAB version are you using?

Comment: I use matlab R2014a (8.3.0.532)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R2014a, imfilter used platform specific libraries in generated code. So only the platforms which is usually the host computer was supported for code generation. In the latest release imfilter generates code for other targets and uses platform specific libraries only for host computer targets.

In short, imfilter is not supported for Cortex-M3 code generation in R2014a.

You can see R2014a documentation for imfilter at http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2014a/images/ref/imfilter.html

Latest documentation is at
http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html

Check out the code generation section in both.